# basic authentication fails with glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, rest, glassfish, jersey

First of all, my apologies for this long post. This is a continuation of my previous question ([Authentication required window popping up after 7u21 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626676/authentication-required-window-popping-up-after-7u21-update)) regarding this issue, but I narrowed down the search. In short, it seems that my BASIC authentication is broken since Java 7u21.

Applets started through JNLP files are not functioning stable at all and gives Authentication Popup windows.

**THE SETUP**

First of all I've set up a **MySQL database** with a usertable and grouptable.

- Table: authentication

[image]

- Table: groups

[image]

Next I have setup a **jdbcRealm** in Glassfish. Notice that the database user and database password fields are empty because I use a JNDI (see further below):

**Glassfish realm settings:**

[image]

**JDNI configuration** (as shown in the domain.xml file):

```
<jdbc-connection-pool connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" wrap-jdbc-objects="false" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="mysql_mit_rohhPool">
  <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mit?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"></property>
  <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
  <property name="Password" value="****"></property>
  <property name="portNumber" value="3306"></property>
  <property name="databaseName" value="mit"></property>
  <property name="User" value="****"></property>
  <property name="serverName" value="localhost"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="mysql_mit_rohhPool" jndi-name="jdbc/DB_MIT"></jdbc-resource>
```

Once this was done, I changed the default realm to the newly created *jdbcRealm* and checked the *Default principal to role mapping*:

[image]

**TESTING**

After all that, for testing I created a simple WebService in Netbeans who fetches some countries from the database and configured the **web.xml** for BASIC authentication:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>Multiple packages, separated by semicolon(;), can be specified in param-value</description>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Basic Protection</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>REST</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>dummy</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbcRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Dummy</description>
    <role-name>dummy</role-name>
</security-role>
```

To test the webservice, I right clicked it in NetBeans and clicked the *Test RESTful Web Service*. A new Internet Explorer window opens and show me a login screen, I enter the credentials for the *dummy* user and everything works.

Next, I create a simple JavaFX FXML project who fetches the countries. I have a class (who uses Jersey) who looks like following. This is generated code by Netbeans 7.3:

```
private WebResource webResource;
private Client client;
private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources";

public CountriesClient() {
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
    client = Client.create(config);
    webResource = client.resource(BASE_URI).path("entities.countries");
}

public void close() {
    client.destroy();
}

public void setUsernamePassword(String username, String password) {
    client.addFilter(new com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
}

public <T> T findAll_XML(Class<T> responseType) throws UniformInterfaceException {
    WebResource resource = webResource;
    return resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
}
```

In my FXML Controller file, I have this method linked to a button:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");

    CountriesClient c = new CountriesClient();
    c.setUsernamePassword("dummy", "****");
    String r = c.findAll_XML(String.class);
    System.out.println(r);
    c.close();
}
```

That is about the setup of my project. Now, when I test this inside Netbeans or I launch this through the *.jar file, everything works as intended and it gives me following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><countriess><countries><country>Belgium</country><id>1</id></countries><countries><country>Ireland</country><id>2</id></countries><countries><country>United Kingdom</country><id>3</id></countries><countries><country>Poland</country><id>4</id></countries></countriess>
```

However, as soon as I start the applet through a *.jnlp file I get this annoying popup complaining about credentials:

[image]

The java console records this:

```
network: Cache entry found [url: http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries
cache: Resource http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries has expired.
cache: Resource http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries has cache control: no-cache.
network: Connecting http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:8080 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Firewall authentication: site=localhost/127.0.0.1:8080, protocol=http, prompt=jdbcRealm, scheme=basic
network: ResponseCode for http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries : 401
network: Encoding for http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries : null
network: Connecting http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries with proxy=DIRECT
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.sun.jersey.core.header.InBoundHeaders: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.sun.jersey.core.util.StringKeyStringValueIgnoreCaseMultivaluedMap: try again ..
network: Downloading resource: http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries
Content-Length: 322
Content-Encoding: null
network: Wrote URL http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries to File C:\Users\stbrunee\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\6\4b456206-236d2196-temp
cache: MemoryCache replacing http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries (refcnt=0). Was: URL: http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries | C:\Users\stbrunee\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\6\4b456206-15cb0b99.idx Now: URL: http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.countries | C:\Users\stbrunee\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\6\4b456206-236d2196.idx
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><countriess><countries><country>Belgium</country><id>1</id></countries><countries><country>Ireland</country><id>2</id></countries><countries><country>United Kingdom</country><id>3</id></countries><countries><country>Poland</country><id>4</id></countries></countriess>
```

On the server side (glassfish log)

```
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET")
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : null
FINE: [Web-Security] Web Permission = ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET")
FINEST: JACC Policy Provider: PolicyWrapper.implies, context (myWS/myWS)- result was(false) permission (("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET"))
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET")
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "HEAD")
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : null
FINE: [Web-Security] Web Permission = ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "HEAD")
FINEST: JACC Policy Provider: PolicyWrapper.implies, context (myWS/myWS)- result was(false) permission (("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "HEAD"))
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "HEAD")
//NOW I PRESS CANCEL AT THE POPUP WINDOW CLIENT SIDE
FINE: [Web-Security] Setting Policy Context ID: old = null ctxID = myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET")
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : null
FINE: [Web-Security] Web Permission = ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET")
FINEST: JACC Policy Provider: PolicyWrapper.implies, context (myWS/myWS)- result was(false) permission (("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET"))
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET")
FINEST: Processing login with credentials of type: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.PasswordCredential
FINE: Logging in user [dummy] into realm: jdbcRealm using JAAS module: jdbcRealm
FINE: Login module initialized: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule
FINEST: JDBC login succeeded for: dummy groups:[dummy]
FINE: JAAS login complete.
FINE: JAAS authentication committed.
FINE: Password login succeeded for : dummy
FINE: Set security context as user: dummy
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/myWS/myWS
FINE: [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : dummy, dummy
FINE: [Web-Security] Web Permission = ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET")
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: true
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/webresources/entities.countries" "GET")
```

There are a few things that I really don't understand:

- On the client side, I see a 401 response code which means Not authorized. How can this be if I use the exact same credentials that I use for testing my webservice?
- On the client side, If I press cancel on the authentication popup windows, why do I still receive the XML data from my request if the user is not properly authenticated?
- On the server side, Still a authentication process is happening. Does this have to do with the fact that this is coded in Java? But again, if the authentication process actually succeeds, why is the authentication popup showing on the client side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the symptoms you encounter is that Oracle has [enabled caching of HTTP responses by default with JDK7 in Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/enhancements-7.html):

> **Caching enabled by default:** Caching of network content for application
>   code running in Web Start mode is now enabled by default. This allows
>   application improved performance and consistency with applet execution
>   mode. To ensure the latest copy of content is used, the application
>   can use `URLConnection.setUseCaches(false)` or request header
>   `Cache-Control` values `no-cache/no-store`.

So what I did was, setting this header after creating the Jersey client:

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter( new HTTPBasicAuthFilter( userId, password ) );
client.addFilter( new ClientFilter() {

    @Override
    public ClientResponse handle( ClientRequest cr )
       throws ClientHandlerException {
           List<Object> cacheControlRequestValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
           cacheControlRequestValues.add( "no-cache" );
           cacheControlRequestValues.add( "no-store" );
           cr.getHeaders().put( HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControlRequestValues );
           return getNext().handle( cr );
    }
}
```

Now if the above specification would be correct, and the implementation of Web Start would follow the [HTTP/1.1 reference](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), which states

> The purpose of the no-store directive is to prevent the inadvertent
>   release or retention of sensitive information (for example, on backup
>   tapes). The no-store directive applies to the entire message, and MAY
>   be sent either in a response or in a request. If sent in a request, a
>   cache MUST NOT store any part of either this request or any response
>   to it.

we would be fine - a network sniffer proved that the client was setting the Cache-Control header correctly. Also a ContainerResponseFilter of Jersey was showing me, that the header on the **request** was set correctly. The **response** on the other hand had no Cache-Control header set. Should not matter according to the specification, but in reality Web Start kept caching the responses!

So I wrote a ContainerResponseFilter that copies the Cache-Control header from the request to the response:

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CacheControlCopyFilter
    implements ContainerResponseFilter 

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter( ContainerRequest containerRequest, ContainerResponse containerResponse ) {
        if ( containerRequest.getRequestHeader( HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL ) != null ) {
            List<Object> responseCacheControlValues = new ArrayList<Object>( containerRequest.getRequestHeader( HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL ).size() );
            for ( String value : containerRequest.getRequestHeader( HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL ) ) {
                responseCacheControlValues.add( value );
            }
            containerResponse.getHttpHeaders().put( HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, responseCacheControlValues );
        }
        return containerResponse;
    }

}
```

and activated it in the `web.xml`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>my.package.CacheControlCopyFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Then you have to delete your Java client cache:

```
"javaws -viewer" -> General
                 -> Settings...
                 -> Delete Files...
                 -> Select all three check boxes
                 -> OK
```

and voilà, no more annoying authentication pop ups :)

Answer (score 2):

I've converted the above code to use the Jersey 2.0 API.

On the client side, the ClientFilter is replaced with the ClientRequestFilter, and the filter's are registered. Also the filter interface doesn't chain like in the 1.0 API.

```
  Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
  client.register(new HttpBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
  client.register(new ClientRequestFilter() {
     @Override
     public void filter(ClientRequestContext crc) throws IOException {
        List<Object> cacheControlRequestValues = new ArrayList<>();
        cacheControlRequestValues.add("no-cache");
        cacheControlRequestValues.add("no-store");
        crc.getHeaders().put(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControlRequestValues);
     }
  });
```

On the server side the interface name, ContainerResponseFilter, is the same, but the method signature is a little different. There is no need for web.xml, as you can specify the @Provider annotation at the beginning of the class (which for me was the tricky part to get the solution to work).

```
@Provider
public class CacheControlCopyFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

   @Override
   public void filter(
           ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
           ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

      if (requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL) != null) {
         List<Object> responseCacheControlValues = new ArrayList<>(
                 requestContext.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL).size());
         for (String value : requestContext.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL)) {
            responseCacheControlValues.add(value);
         }
         responseContext.getHeaders().put(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, responseCacheControlValues);
      }
   }
}
```